# Which is faster, int or long if targeting 32 and 64 bit platforms

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will using longs instead of ints benefit in 64bit java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903235/will-using-longs-instead-of-ints-benefit-in-64bit-java)

I have an algorithm that needs to be optimised as much as possible.  The received wisdom is that integer maths is fastest when the primitive op types are the same "bitness" as the CPU.  If I am targeting 32 and 64 bit platforms, is there any performance difference between int and long?

Comment: Damn, missed it.  Thanks.  A very good discussion.

Comment: The cache misses argument is a strong one.

Comment: Yep, that pretty much does it for me, especially as one of my targets is Android.