# Faster program when using long instead of int

Tags: java, algorithm, int, long-integer

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Given an integer n, return the number of trailing zeroes in n!.
>
> Note: Your solution should be in logarithmic time complexity.

I submitted the following code which was rejected as too slow:

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
        int result = 0;
        int k = 5;

        while (k <= n){
            result += n / k;
            k *= 5;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But when I changed the variable k to long, it was fast enough/

Why is it faster when I declare k as long instead of int? (I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903235/will-using-longs-instead-of-ints-benefit-in-64bit-java) which, if I understand correctly, says the opposite should happen)

Comment: Probably you are hitting an integer overflow for variable `k`. It's not that the code is faster, it's that it simply doesn't work with integer!

Comment: In favor of ten million questions, you're hitting an integer overflooooooow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tunaki's comment is probably on the money. If your `n` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 5`, then it's possible for `k` to reach a value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 5`, then after multiplying by 5, it overflows and becomes a small number again, so your program never terminates.

Whereas, if `k` is a long, then it doesn't matter if its value is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 5`; as long as it's smaller than `Long.MAX_VALUE / 5` (which it's guaranteed to be, since `n` is an int and ints never reach values close enough), the overflow won't occur.

Answer (score 2):

`k` could overflow, meaning you might get an infinite loop (i.e. cases where `k <= n` is always true, since `k` could wrap around to `INT_MIN` when multiplied by 5).

For example, consider the case where `n` is `INT_MAX`: `k <= n` must be true if `k` is an `int`.

If `k` is a `long`, though, then there's no potential for overflow.